# Generate numbers (1,2,3, etc....) after set value

Tags: sql-server, numbers

(mssql , t-sql)

I have a field with **dummy** values and "*null*"

```
SELECT 
    [P_ID] ,
    [DATE],
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY P_ID ORDER BY DATE),DATE) >5
        OR ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [P_ID] ORDER BY [DATE] ) = 1 THEN 'Dummy'
            END AS [TEMP]

from #temp
```

if there is more then 5 days between the first row and the row over it (lag() ) then "dummy"

[image]

I would like to add numbers to the "*null*" value so that my TEMP column would look like my **OUTPUT** column.

```
TEMP    OUTPUT
dummy   dummy
NULL    1
dummy   dummy
NULL    1
dummy   dummy
NULL    1
NULL    2
NULL    3
dummy   dummy
NULL    1
NULL    2
dummy   dummy
NULL    1
NULL    2
NULL    3
NULL    4
NULL    5
NULL    6
NULL    7
NULL    8
NULL    9
NULL    10
NULL    11
NULL    12
NULL    13
NULL    14
NULL    15
NULL    16
NULL    17
NULL    18
NULL    19
NULL    20
NULL    21
NULL    22
NULL    23
NULL    24
NULL    25
NULL    26
```

Comment: It looks like your pattern is depending on the ordering of the rows in the table.  But, alas, tables represent *unordered* sets and have no ordering.  Do you have another column such as an identity column that specifies the ordering?

Comment: Considering the fact that tables in a relational datanase are unsorted by nature, I don't see how you can do that without another colum that will provide the order.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I don't get the `random` in your question's title. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please have a look at my OUTPUT do that help?

Comment: Please google "SQL Gaps and Islands problem".   This has been solved many times.